# Representation of n digits number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am confused in the representation of $n$ digits number. If $N$ is a natural number with $n$ digits. Then $a_n, a_{n-1}, \ldots$ represents the  number $N$. But if for example $N$ is the $3$ digits number. What would be the value of $a_0$ digit. Because obviously $3$ digits number has $3$ digits $(n_3, n_2, n_1)$.

I hope u understand my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an indexing problem, if you start indexing from $0$ and in total there are $n$ digits, the last index should be $n-1$.

$$N = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i \cdot 10^i,    \text{ where } 0 \le a_i \le 9$$

For example, the number $123$ has $a_0=3, a_1=2, a_2=1$.

In contrast, if you start your index from $1$, then the last index should be $n$.

$$N = \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i \cdot 10^{i-1},     \text{ where } 0 \le b_i \le 9$$

For example, the number $123$ has $b_1=3, b_2=2, b_3=1$.

Comment: What is the general accepted notation? If u represent natural number with n digits. For example 321 is 3 digits number. Should i call 3 as (a sub 2) then obviously a(sub n) is actually a(sub n-1)

Comment: personally I prefer starting from $0$ as I don't have to introduce $i-1$ in the power of basis. I think we want to write out the formula explicilty to avoid any confusion, rather than writing $a_i$ without defining them.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously an $n$ digit number is represented as $a_{n-1} a_{n-2} \ldots a_0$ not $a_n a_{n-1} \ldots a_1$.

Comment: So how u call it n digits number when it has total n + 1 digits?

Comment: Please read my post again.